# MySQL - Get Minimum Value, Data From Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql-5.5, select

Good evening all, first post on the DBA forums.  I am having real issues working out how to accomplish a seemingly simple task within MySQL as a model for PHP code later on.  I am not exactly a MySQL noob, but definitely not an expert either.  :)  Here's the scenario.

There are 2 tables primarily involved here.  The first (tblZipCodeServed) has 3 columns:

- zipcodeservedID (auto increment field for unique ID)
- zipcodeservedStaffID (staff memeber ID)
- zipcodeservedZipCode (actual ZIP being served)

The second table (tblZipCodeDist) has 4 columns:

- zipcodedistID (auto increment field for unique ID)
- zipcodedistStartZip (starting ZIP code for distance measurement)
- zipcodedistEndZip (ending ZIP code for distance measurement)
- zipcodedistMiles (miles between the 2 zip codes)

So the ultimate objective here is to figure out which staff member currently serves the ZIP Code closest to that of a new enrollee, to help the coordinators figure out who should be assigned to the new enrollee.  Each staff member serves multiple ZIP codes, so I need to get the miles between each ZIP code they currently service and the target ZIP code... but only display/return/whatever the smallest number of miles.  This data would need to be added as a column in a currently existing query to show assorted other info that assists the coordinators in their decision making.  Here's a totally fictitious example to show what I mean:

New enrollee Tom B lives in ZIP code 12345.  Staff member David Z currently serves 4 zip codes, the mileage from 12345 being: 4.6, 5.5, 8.7, and 12.0 miles.  Staff member Anna T currently serves 5 ZIP codes, the mileage from 12345 being: 2.4, 4.1, 12.8, 16.2, and 21.0 miles.  Staff member Dawn J currently serves 3 ZIP codes, the mileage from 12345 being: 0.2, 1.6, and 7.7 miles.  When coordinator Janie C adds Tom B to the system and clicks the button to help her decide the staff member assignment, she should see something like the following:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Staff Name | {assorted cols} | Miles From ZIP |
|------------+-----------------+----------------|
| Dawn J     | {assorted data} | 0.2            |
| Anna T     | {assorted data) | 2.4            |
| David Z    | {assorted data) | 4.6            |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried straight-up select queries, joins, unions, subqueries - even dabbled in stored procedures (though I had no idea what I was doing) - all of which were subsequentally deleted as they didn't work and I am fairly annoyed about the whole thing.  I know the process I need to execute to get what I want out of the DB, I just don't know how to get there.  The process, in my head, is as follows:

1. Get all StaffIDs and Zip Codes Served (from tblZipCodeServed), one staffID at a time
2. For each staffID, loop through all Zip Codes Served, looking up the distance between it and the target zip in tblZipCodeDist to get miles.
3. Print/Return/Capture lowest mileage amount
4. Move on to next staffID
5. Repeat 2-4 for each staffID
6. Print lowest mileage as additional column in existing report.

Can someone point me in the right direction?  I am not necessarily looking for anyone to code/author/create this for me (though if it's quick and easy for you experts, and you wouldn't mind, I certainly wouldn't be mad)... I just need some pointers as I am apparently missing some key concept here.  Maybe there's a MySQL tool/function I don't know about?  Maybe I am just not up to this ninja level as of yet?  Whatever the issue is here, I would greatly appreciate any and all help you can provide.

Thank you very much, in advance!!

**EDIT - My Solution**
Thanks to ypercube for the answer... here's what I came up with (all fields listed, not just the snippet) that seems to do the trick (in PHP, but the same concept... $pzc is a stand-in for "ParentZipCode", while $cpl is a stand-in for "ChildPriLang" - both of which are fed in via web form):

```
$getrecquery = "select DISTINCT a.staffID, concat(a.staffFName, \" \", a.staffLName) as HVNAME, a.staffBaseZip, c.zipcodedistStartZip, c.zipcodedistEndZip, "
    . "c.zipcodedistMiles, a.staffCaseLoadMax-(select count(*) from tblRoster d where d.rosterStaffID = a.staffID) as CasesLeft, "
    . "(select min(c.zipcodedistMiles) from tblStaffZipServed b, tblZipCodeDist c "
    . "where ((c.zipcodedistStartZip = b.staffzipservedZipCode) OR (c.zipcodedistEndZip = b.staffzipservedZipCode)) AND "
    . "((c.zipcodedistStartZip = $pzc) OR (c.zipcodedistEndZip = $pzc)) AND b.staffzipservedStaffID = a.staffID) as MinMiles "
    . "from tblStaff a, tblStaffZipServed b, tblZipCodeDist c, tblRoster d "
    . "where a.staffID = b.staffzipservedStaffID and "
    . "((c.zipcodedistStartZip = $pzc) and (c.zipcodedistEndZip = a.staffBaseZip)) or "
    . "((c.zipcodedistEndZip = $pzc) and (c.zipcodedistStartZip = a.staffBaseZip)) and "
    . "(a.staffPriLang = $cpl or a.staffAltLang = $cpl) and "
    . "a.staffCaseLoadMax-(select count(*) from tblRoster d where d.rosterStaffID = a.staffID) > 0 "
    . "order by MinMiles, c.zipcodedistMiles, CasesLeft, HVNAME;";
```

This query outputs exactly what I need.  The key for me was using the subquery as a column and getting that to work properly, rearranging pieces of it's where clause until I got the desired output.

Hopefully this info can help someone else out in the future!!

**END EDIT**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a `Staff` table, it would be a query similar to this:

```
SELECT 
    s.*,                         -- needed columns from Staff table
    MIN(d.zipcodedistMiles) AS Miles_From_ZIP
FROM 
    Staff AS s
  LEFT JOIN
    tblZipCodeServed AS z
      ON  z.zipcodeservedStaffID = s.StaffID
  LEFT JOIN
    tblZipCodeDist AS d
      ON  d.zipcodedistStartZip = z.zipcodeservedZipCode
      AND d.zipcodedistEndZip = @TargetZipCode
GROUP BY
    s.StaffID ;                  -- the Primary Key of Staff
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, ypercube!  I appreciate it greatly.  I will edit my post with the query I came up with... but you certainly earned points in my book here as you were on the same thought track I was.  :)